# Reseting variable

Tags: variable

I don't even know how I should ask the question. I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

I want to order entries by year-month and output single value *(from certain number fields)* from all entries from a month like so:

1. *( July(10) )*
2. *( August(20) )*
3. *( September(30) )*

Here is the piece of code I'm trying to figure out:

```
[
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('orders').limit(null).order('postDate desc') %}

{% set currentMonthEarning = 0 %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntries | group("postDate.year") %}
    {% for month, entries in entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('F')" ) %}
        {% for entry in entries %}

            {# fetch aPrice, bPrice, cPrice, but only if > 0 #}
            {% set aPrice = (entry.aPrice > 0) ? entry.aPrice : 0 %}
            {% set bPrice = (entry.bPrice > 0) ? entry.bPrice : 0 %}
            {% set cPrice = (entry.cPrice > 0) ? entry.cPrice : 0 %}

            {% set currentMonthEarning = currentMonthEarning + aPrice + bPrice + cPrice %}

        {% endfor %}

        {{ currentMonthEarning }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
]
```

**Desire output would be:** `[10,20,30]`

**What's going on there actually?:** It loops through current year's entries from section `mySection`, then months and then entries. While it loops through `entries`, it does summing up of three number fields and sets it into the variable `currentMonthEarning` outside the `entries` loop.

**Current output:** `[10,30,70]`

It seems that `currentMonthEarning` is passed over to the next "month" with a value set from previous "month" in the loop. The value for the last month (latest) is correct because of `('postDate desc')`. If you understand what I'd like can you find a way to get it done?

Comment: Not sure I'm fully understanding, but are you looking to just reset `currentMonthEarning` after outputting its value?  i.e. `{{ currentMonthEarning }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}{% set currentMonthEarning = 0 %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three `for` loops, and are setting `currentMonthEarning` to `0` outside of all of them, and then adding to it (and never resetting it to `0`).

Probably you should move the `{% set currentMonthEarning = 0 %}` inside either the first or second `for` loop.